# Path for file in Directory

Tags: html, css, image, path

I have an 'css' folder and am trying to access an image in there.  I am in the parent directory and the images folder is in there.  How do I write the path?  Nothing I do is working..

```
<img src="..\images\final2.gif" class="stretch" alt="" />
```

Comment: accessing the path in HTML or CSS?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and you haven't showed what you've attempted. Please update your question with clarification (are you trying to do this in CSS or HTML) and some code that shows you attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: You'll probably find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Comment: According to your html, you are looking for the image in the parent directory from where the html file is.

Comment: Now, where is the image located?

Comment: its in a folder called 'css'

Comment: If you're trying to access an image in the css folder, then your path should reference the css folder... `<img src="css/final2.gif">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<img src="images/final2.gif" class="stretch" alt="" />
```

or

```
<img src="../images/final2.gif" class="stretch" alt="" />
```

**explanation**

```
<img src="../images/final2.gif">
          __ ______ ________
          |    |       |
          |    |       |___ 3. get the filenamed "final2.gif".
          |    |
          |    |___ 2. go inside "images/" subdirectory.
          | 
          | 
          |____ 1. Go one level up.
```

Comment: @stackover updated answer check again  .

Comment: that worked.  I just needed to make them forward slashes.  thanks!

Comment: @stackover good :) Happy to help :)

Comment: please remove downvote :(

Comment: @stackover i didn't down-vote i'm the only one who up-voted you  .

Answer (score 0):

if you have a structure like :

```
root
    various web pages
    css
       img
```

from the css you'd simply have src = "imagename.ext"
if you're accessing from the root folder where the html files might be it would be src = "css/imagename.ext"

EDIT:
After you edited the question.

the "../" is going up a folder.  If you're already in the directory there's no need to include that, you can simply use images/final2.gif

Example from my site:

```
 background:url('../img/backgrounds/background1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

in this instance the images are in the directory above the one that the css file is in.  The parent directory as already mentioned.

Comment: would I use forward or backward slashes?

Comment: in your case, forward.

Comment: @stackover - can you provide your folder structure.  Knowing the images are in a folder called css is useful but not when we have no idea where that folder is in relation to others :)